# discord.py current time command

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have this time command, and I want it so that when I say `p!time`, it would say `PST time:, EST time:, etc`

```py
if message.content.startswith('p!time'):
        timestamp = datetime.now()
        await message.channel.send(timestamp)
        await message.channel.send(timestamp.strftime(r"%I:%M %p"))
        #now idk what to do
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change timezone, it can be done using a library called `pytz`

```
$ pip install pytz
```

Code:

```py
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

if message.content.startswith('p!time'):
    timestamp = datetime.now()
    pst = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
    est = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
    msg = f"PST Time: {timestamp.astimezone(pst).strftime("%I:%M %p")}, EST Time: {timestamp.astimezone(est).strftime("%I:%M %p")}"
    await message.channel.send(msg)
```